# Store data from one Class to Another

Tags: java, model-view-controller, collections, java.util.scanner

In this I have tried the Registration Form in Model View Control architecture. I am unable to Store the User Data In Another class. In that the Registration field Has to be stored in the Registration Database Class and Contact information has to be stored in the Contact Information Class.

Then how Should I frame Main method

```
public class RegistrationData {

private String username;
private String password;
private Contact contact;

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public Contact getContact() {
    return contact;
}

public void setContact(Contact contact) {
    this.contact = contact;
}

public RegistrationData(String username, String password, Contact contact) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.contact = contact;
 }
}

public class Contact {

private String name;
private String phoneNumber;
private String emailId;

public Contact(String name, String phoneNumber, String emailId) {
    this.name = name;
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    this.emailId = emailId;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getPhoneNumber() {
    return phoneNumber;
}

public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}

public String getEmailId() {
    return emailId;
}

public void setEmailId(String emailId) {
    this.emailId = emailId;
 }
}

public class Registration {

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
void Registration(RegistrationData registrationData,Contact contact){
    System.out.println("Username : ");registrationData.setUsername(scanner.next());
    System.out.println("Password : ");registrationData.setPassword(scanner.next());
    System.out.println("Name : ");contact.setName(scanner.next());
    System.out.println("PhoneNumber : ");contact.setPhoneNumber(scanner.next());
    System.out.println("Email id :");contact.setEmailId(scanner.next());
}
}

//Data Base Class

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class RegistrationDatabase {

List<RegistrationData> registrationData = new ArrayList<>();


public void storeData(RegistrationData registrationData){
    this.registrationData.add(registrationData);
    System.out.println(this.registrationData);
 }
 }

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class ContactDatabase {

List<Contact> contacts = new LinkedList<>();

public void addContact(Contact contact){
    this.contacts.add(contact);
}
}
```

Comment: Hi i am not completely sure what you are trying to accomplish here. Do you just want some Registrations to be added to both DataBases (ArrayLists)?.

Comment: yes i just want to store registered value to the respective database class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct me If I am wrong in interpreting you question

**Assumption 1 :** 
You want to Store registration data to RegistrationInformation table from Contact Information class as well as from RegistrationInformation class

**Solution 1:**
As I can see there is one to one relation between Contact and registration,so You can add a association in ContactInformation class as well as you have done in RegisterInformation class

```
public class Contact {
//one to one relation
private RegistrationData registrationData;
.
.
.
.
```

and use this to store registration from Contact

**Assumption 2 :**
You have seperate database for Contact and Registration

**Solution 2:**

In that case Create a POJO class for Registration form(same as RegistrationData,but will be used to capture data from view) and then create two classes RegistrationData and Contact class and then Use the POJO to retrieve and store the information in both the database.